# Trouble installing wxPython 4.0.7 on Python 3.7.0 in Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, wxpython

I have Python 3.7.0 installed on Windows 10. I want to install a *particular* version of wxPython - wxPython 4.0.7.

I have tried the following command, which ends up installing the *latest* version:

```
pip install wxpython
```

I also tried installing the specific version using the following:

```
pip install wxPython==4.0.7
```

It starts installing, but eventually there is an error: "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

How to install this version?

Edit:
`python --version` shows Python 3.7.0
`pip --version` shows pip 10.0.1

Comment: Please show `python --version`, `pip --version` and the text of the entire error,

Comment: @phd added version information. However, strangely, using the second command I showed above has now worked, and wxPython 4.0.7 is installed.

Comment: `pip` is certainly too old. I recommend to upgrade it.